# Matplotlib runs out of memory

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Here is the code that I'm using to plot many plots and save them, but it is eating up all of the available RAM and causes the notebook to crash. I tried adding `fig.clf()`, `del fig`, `gc.collect`, and yet nothing seems to work.
I'm able to save only 38 figures around, then session gets crashed on Google Colab, since RAM gets full.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print(np.__version__) # 1.19.5
print(mpl.__version__) # 3.2.2, also tried with latest 3.4.1

x = np.arange(0, 280, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)

for k in range(100):
  fig, ax = plt.subplots(6, 2, sharex = True)
  fig.set_size_inches(37.33, 21)

  for i in range(2):
    for j in range(6):
      ax[j][i].plot(x, y)

  fig.savefig(f'figure{k}.png', dpi = 300)
  plt.close(fig)
```

Comment: We can't solve performance issues by looking at pseudocode. Provide an MCVE. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Done, Added a MCVE.

Comment: Do you really want to create 100 separate images of 12 plots each? It took me roughly 7 seconds to generate just the first image (done outside of Jupyter).  Please also add the necessary imports to your example, and the version numbers of the libraries you're using.

Comment: Yes, Actually I want to create 200 separate images of 12 plots each, each plot contains 2.8k lines of data. But it could only create 38. Added necessary imports and the version numbers of the libraries as well. Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to the inline backend. The memory leak can be avoided by explicitly switching to the agg backend.
cross ref: [matplotlib/issues/20067](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/20067)

Answer (score 0):

maybe if you try to save each figure after it is generated, I mean try putting `fig. savefig` in the for loop.
Edit: after looking for the issue on google, I found that you might need to buy Colab pro.

Comment: Its already in the outermost for loop, after plotting all of the subplots.